# how do i write a batch file to rdp into a server through a batch script

Tags: mstsc

how do i write a batch file to rdp into a server through a batch script. i started mstsc through script but there was a **problem in clicking on buttons in window pop-ups**.what i did was included a vbs script in my batch scipt(using arrow keys and enter keys)..but it did'nt workout.Any help to rectify the problem is appreciated...

here is the vbs code name: test2.vbs

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 5000
WshShell.AppActivate "Remote Desktop Connection"
WshShell.SendKeys "{LEFT}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

batch file has:

```
mstsc /v:172.28.52.18 /admin
cscript /nologo test2.vbs
pause
```